# Сложная верстка бутстрап

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сверстать такой блок, чтобы красный горизонтальный блок снизу, и темно-серый сверху были на всю ширину монитора, но при этом чтобы в них контент был в контенейре. Также с левым блоком логотипа.

Красные вертикальные линии - должен быть container bootstrap'a

[image]

Comment: никто не знает?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.additional {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2" style="background:red">Logo</div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="row additional">
        <div class="col-12" style="background:antiquewhite">1</div>
        <div class="col-12" style="background:silver">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сымитировать у .container-fluid и у содержимого .container одинаковые фоны по левую и правую стороны. Сделать это можно, например, так:

```css
.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #3A3A3A;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #CC293A;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #6A6A6A;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.row, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-9 {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  color: red;
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 42px;
  background-color: #6A6A6A;
}

.in-top {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #3A3A3A;
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
}

.in-bottom {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #CC293A;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">LOGO</div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
        <div class="in-top">EN RU</div>
        <div class="in-bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

То есть мы сначала с помощью 3-х абсолютно спозиционированных блоков раскрашиваем .container-fluid, а потом накладываем поверх этого .container с содержимым, где блоки внутри контейнера тоже раскрашены соответствующим образом.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0; background-color: red;">
  <div class="container" style="color: #fff">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In dolor qui voluptatum, assumenda, accusamus ipsam iure. Quod labore recusandae, temporibus voluptas ducimus quidem provident totam explicabo cum officiis aliquam adipisci! Labore, adipisci deleniti esse optio blanditiis ut ipsa incidunt at beatae ipsum atque magni, quisquam tempora quis debitis, nesciunt maiores praesentium? Doloribus alias, delectus ratione inventore quisquam in vitae nam, neque perspiciatis reprehenderit necessitatibus ducimus saepe laboriosam incidunt nisi. Hic nobis a dolorem perspiciatis laboriosam et voluptate maiores, officia laudantium, totam fugit laborum necessitatibus. Ex in ipsum nulla delectus expedita et repellat laboriosam maxime, a itaque pariatur consectetur enim, impedit!</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Во-первых, код ужасен, а во-вторых, как он вообще к вопросу относится?

Comment: Я для примера показал, какие классы нужно прописать.
То, что код не идеален, - есть разница? Я навел пример, что все работает. Над кодом я долго не стал париться. А если ты говоришь за `<link>` в коде, это я просто подключил библиотеку bootstrap, чтобы видеть как все работает.

Comment: Нет, я про то, что ты вкладываешь containr'ы друг в друга и сбрасываешь паддинги. И как код относится к вопросу, я до сих пор не понимаю.

Comment: Ему нужен фон на всю ширину монитора - это `container-fluid`, ему нужна в этом `container-fluid` заданая конкретная ширина, - можно использовать свой класс, например, 'wrap` и задать ему свою ширину. Если я не правильно понял вопрос, тогда не отвлекайся на это, проходи дальше.

Comment: Это ведь совершенно не то, что требовалось. Ты просто залил блок красным, ты хоть картинку в вопросе смотрел? Зачем давать совершенно недоработанный ответ?